# I want to remove string after space" ", but length is variable and string can be of any length

Tags: mysql, sql, substr

I want to remove string after space `' '`,  but length is variable and string can be of any length.
for Example ;-

```
 as full name Nikhil Sharma
              Nikhil Arora
              Digvender Chauhan
```

i want to remove all words after space

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, CHARINDEX(';', MyText) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(';', MyText) > 0
```

This is not working
Answer is with help of CAse, Regexp.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Why are you using `';'` if you want to search for space?

Comment: Just change `';'` to `' '`, WTP?

Comment: phpmyadmin i dont want to search for space

Comment: actually, i want to del all characters after space in a string as i have shown in example

Comment: You delete the characters after space by replacing with the characters before it after searching.

Comment: `PhpMyAdmin` is not a database. It's a web application for managing and querying a MySQL database.

Comment: `CHARINDEX()` is not a MySQL function, it's a SQL-Server function. The analogous function in MySQL is `LOCATE()`.

Comment: can you show me a Syntax with help of case and regexp to del characters after space

Comment: that charindex function, i have just copied paste it from anywhere  it was not what i'm using    Kindly show me the right Syntax

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL the function name is `LOCATE()`. Then search for `' '` instead of `';'`.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, LOCATE(' ', MyText)-1)
WHERE LOCATE(' ', MyText) != 0
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jGNpJPdqmcX25ZdsV2w1YK/0)

Explanation:

`LOCATE(' ', MyText)` returns the position of the first space in `MyText`.

`LEFT(MyText, n)` returns the leftmost `n` characters of `MyText`.

So if the space is in position `4`, we subtract `1` from that position, and return the leftmost `3` characters. That removes everything from the space to the end of the string.

`LOCATE()` returns `0` if it can't find the substring, so the test `WHERE LOCATE(' ', MyText) != 0` makes it only update rows where the column contains a space.

Comment: That's what you asked, that's what this does.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: No, that's not the way we work here.

Comment: You can post a link to sqlfiddle.com with an example.

Comment: That's just checking if the string has a space, so it doesn't bother doing the replacement if there's no space.

Comment: I've added a link to a demo.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, ' ', 1) FROM table_name;
```

and

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, ' ', 1);
```

accordingly.

Comment: Thanx A lot sir. That's what i was looking for.